# DOM7000: Access Denied. Resource access is restricted for cross-origin URL: 'blob:XXXXxxxxx

Tags: javascript, dom, windows-store-apps, winjs

*Original question from MSDN forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d37a169-34eb-4112-a1f4-e725e77dc81d/dom7000-access-denied-resource-access-is-restricted-for-crossorigin-url), but since nobody has answered I decided to give a try on SO.*

I had been using a way for users to upload images from their local computer to my server (DB). But now I'm adding the possibility to shrink the image a little bit, so if the users selects (via `FileOpenPicker`) a huge image, I would scale it down a bit before showing it in an `img` element and upload it to the server (on user request).

After doing that, I get the warning from the subject in the JavaScript Console when I want to set the `img.src` attribute via `URL.createObjectURL` as I've always done it. Also, when I try to upload the file I get a "Access denied" error.

Could somebody please help? Here's a little code snippet.

```
var pixelData, newFile;
file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read)
.then(function (origin) {
    return Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(origin);
}.bind(this)).then(function (bitmapDecoder) {
    var bitmapTransform = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform();
    bitmapTransform.scaledHeight = 768;
    bitmapTransform.scaledWidth = 1024;

    return bitmapDecoder.getPixelDataAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight, bitmapTransform, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ExifOrientationMode.respectExifOrientation, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ColorManagementMode.doNotColorManage);
}.bind(this)).then(function (data) {
    pixelData = data;
    var fileName = this.maximumUploadSize + '_' + file.name;
    return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.temporaryFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting);
}.bind(this)).then(function (aux) {
    newFile = aux;
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.add(newFile, newFile.name);
    return newFile.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
}.bind(this)).then(function (destination) {
    return Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId, destination);
}.bind(this)).then(function (encoder) {
    encoder.setPixelData(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.premultiplied, 1024, 768, 96, 96, pixelData.detachPixelData());
    return encoder.flushAsync();
}.bind(this)).then(function () {
    this.internalSet(newFile);
}.bind(this), function (error) {
    Utils.showError(error);
});
```

and this is the code of the internalSet function, the one that actually sets the src property

```
this.image = file;
if (file) {
    this.imgTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.image, { oneTimeOnly: true });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like the error is a known issue right now: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797361/ie-10-treats-blob-url-as-cross-origin-and-denies-access